# What is best practice when it comes to react Microfrontend Architecture and React Router Best Practices

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom, micro-frontend, webpack-module-federation

I am working on building a microfrontend POC in React using ModuleFederation

My question surrounds best practices when it comes routing ['react-router-dom v6']

Currently, I have my application split into 3 separate microfrontends: Shell, Container, Header

In my case, my `Header` needs access to the url params to be able to `read params` using useParams hook provided by react-router-dom

For this to happen, I must provide a path inside react router to have access

Header MFE

```
<Router>
 <Routes>
    <Route path="/stores/:storeId/:tabId/*" element={<Header />} />
 </Routes>
</Router>
```

When I export this using ModuleFederation, I am currently omitting the wrapped router and just exposing the `<Header />` so that the `Container` can provider the Router, etc

This is where I run into my conundrum...

My `Header` component will technically live outside the main router so that the Container can serve its routes and respective paths

Container MFE

```
<Layout style={{ minHeight: '100vh' }}>
  <Header /> <== does not work / no access to params
  <MainContent>
    <Routes>
       <Route
         path="/stores/:storeId/dashboard"
         element={<h3>dashboard</h3>}
       />
    </Routes>
  </MainContent>
</Layout>
```

Normally this would not be a problem except the fact that both the `Header` and `dashboard` component technically fall within the same route restricting me the ability to group in main route as seen below.

Duplicated routes

```
<Layout style={{ minHeight: '100vh' }}>
  <MainContent>
    <Routes>
       <Route path="/stores/:storeId/:tabId/*" element={
         <>
           <Header />
           <MainContent>
             <Outlet />
           <MainContent>
         </>
         }>
         <Route
           path="/stores/:storeId/dashboard"
           element={<h3>dashboard</h3>}
         />
      </Route>
    </Routes>
  </MainContent>
</Layout>
```

`path="/stores/:storeId/:tabId/*` <= header nav needs access to these params so it will only load if this route is matched

`path="/stores/:storeId/dashboard"` <= direct route in which :tabId equals dashboard in this case

I want the header to always be present

I experimented with this approach and it worked but it seems dirty:

```
<Layout style={{ minHeight: '100vh' }}>
  <Routes>
     <Route path="/stores/:storeId/:tabId/*" element={<Header />} />
  </Routes>
  <MainContent>
    <Routes>
       <Route
         path="/stores/:storeId/dashboard"
         element={<h3>dashboard</h3>}
       />
    </Routes>
  </MainContent>
</Layout>
```

Is this a bad practice or am I looking at it the wrong way and this is in fact okay to do?

Should I be exporting the `<Header />` wrapped in its own routes?

Answer (score 0):

After digging deeper into the documentation, it seems having many  declarations is acceptable

[React Router v6](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/overview#multiple-sets-of-routes)